# Nginx HEAD requests returning 404 for some routes

Tags: nginx

I'm having trouble finding out why two routes in my website are returning 404 on HEAD requests as the routes do respond correctly for GET requests.

The routes in question are `/history/*` and `/page/*`, both respond with 404 on HEAD requests. But all other routes respond fine to HEAD, like `/about` and `/`.

At first I though it could be either the `sub_filter` or the `expire off`, but the `/` route also have them and works fine.

When checking the logs nginx complains about open() not finding file `/page/1`, so I tried removing the `location /` block but no difference.

I also tried removing the block that limits the request methods, but also makes no difference.

Here's the core of my nginx config (I've removed location blocks for images, https redirection, HSTS and CSP headers for clarity)

```
server {
  error_page 401 403 404 /404.html;

  if ($request_method !~ ^(GET|HEAD|POST)$ ) {
    return 405;
  }

  location ~ /page/(\d+)$ {
    set $htype 'page';
    set $hpage $1;
    set $hcanonicalurl '/$htype/$hpage';
    index /index.html;
  }

  location ~* /history/([a-z0-9-]+)$ {
    set $htype 'history';
    set $hpage '$1';
    set $hcanonicalurl '/$htype/$hpage';
    index /index.html;
  }

  location = / {
    set $htype 'page';
    set $hpage '1';
    set $hcanonicalurl '/';
    index /index.html;
  }

  location = /index.html {
    if ( $htype = '' ) {
      set $htype 'page';
      set $hpage 1;
      set $hcanonicalurl '/';
    }

    sub_filter_once off;
    sub_filter '%H_PAGE%' '$hcanonicalurl';
    sub_filter '%H_IMAGE%' '${htype}_$hpage';

    expires off;
    add_header Pragma no-cache;
    add_header Cache-Control "no-store";
  }

  location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
  }
}
```

Comment: So `GET /page/1` is working? And which file on the filesystem is being served?

Comment: @IVOGELOV Yes GET is working, it's serving the `index.html` file. The internal redirect then calls the `location = /index.html` block which makes the text replacement and set the no-cache headers. That's the same behaviour for the `/history/article-title` route.

Comment: Your config seems a little unusual to me. I think that the easiest way to find out what is happening is to turn on the debug log of nginX (you might need to recompile nginX or install a debug-enabled version - since most distributions provide just the non-debug package by default). Debug log will show exactly which location blocks are traversed and in what sequence, and what filename is being searched on the filesystem.

Comment: @IVOGELOV Found the solution, thanks for the help. I've put the solution and its explanation below so others might better understand the directives.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with the config above is that both routes do not end with a slash `/`.

The documentation for the `index` directive [states](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_index_module.html#index):

> The `ngx_http_index_module` module processes requests ending with the slash character (‘/’).

Or "`index` only works on routes that end with slash".

So even though the location blocks were being selected correctly, the `index` directive would fail as the routes did not end with a slash. This would then trigger the `location /` block followed by the `try_file` with an internal redirect to `location = /index.html` block that would then render a **200** response. Or in other words, **GET** was working out of pure luck.

So how to fix? Adding the ending slash would fix the problem but only if my routes ended with slash, so requesting `/page/1` would not fall under the location block and making the slash optional would just keep the problem.

Thus the correct way to fix this is by exchanging the `index` directive with `error_page`. As the documentation for `try_files` [explains](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#try_files):

> In the following example,
>
> ```
> location / {
>     try_files $uri $uri/ @drupal;
> }
> ```
>
> the try_files directive is equivalent to
>
> ```
> location / {
>     error_page 404 = @drupal;
>     log_not_found off;
> }
> ```

So here's a fixed version. Notice that I'm using different directives for each block only to demonstrate two possible solutions:

```
server {
  location ~ /page/(\d+)$ {
    set $htype 'page';
    set $hpage $1;
    set $hcanonicalurl '/$htype/$hpage';
    error_page 404 = /index.html;
    log_not_found off;
  }

  location ~* /history/([a-z0-9-]+)$ {
    set $htype 'history';
    set $hpage '$1';
    set $hcanonicalurl '/$htype/$hpage';
    try_files $uri /index.html;
  }
```

You may also change `$uri` inside the `try_files` to `failme` or another file you can be sure will never exist so it always falls under the `/index` redirect.